# Visual WebGUI change theme

Tags: c#, visual-web-gui

I am using **VisualwebGUI** in my application. Its working fine. The problem is, i am setting a theme in application **properties -> Registration** .

But as per the requirement, change theme option should come in a frontend and user can change the themes. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the current theme in runtime by modifying `Context.CurrentTheme` Form property, or `VWGContext.CurrentTheme` static property. The value should be a name of theme configured in Registration.